# Java convert string to int

Tags: java, string, int

I have a string. I split and store it as a `char` array . I am trying to convert it using `Integer.parseInt` and I get an error. How do I convert String to int?

Here's my code:

```
String tab[]= null;
tab=pesel.split("");
int temp=0;
for(String tab1 : tab)
{
    temp=temp+3*Integer.parseInt(tab1); //error
}
```

Comment: What was the error? Did you try printing the string to make sure it represented a number? Why `split("")`?

Comment: Please show what your input looks like and what your expected output should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a string of digits (e.g. `"123"`), you can use [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) instead:

```
for (char c : pesel.toCharArray()) {
    temp += 3 * (c - '0');
}
```

This avoids `Integer.parseInt()` altogether. If you want to ensure that each character is a digit, you can use [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29).

---

Your error is because `str.split("")` contains a leading empty string in the array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("123".split("")));
```

```
[, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now, there *is* a trick using negative lookaheads to avoid that:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("123".split("(?!^)")));
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Although, in any case, I would prefer the approach shown above.

Comment: @LoganMurphy Sure, I made a note of that.

Comment: Nice code, thx for help. I dont saw space on input when I print my spilit string.

Comment: @set4812 `str.split("")` will *always* contain a leading empty string.

Comment: This is possible to see leading empty string on output?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a gap in split method.

```
tab=pesel.split(" ");
```

Comment: Not if the string is just a sequence of digits.